# Unable to do logging to a file in a jsf web application

Tags: java, web-applications, logging, jsf-2

Im using websphere server and JSF 2.0

In my managed bean i have declared the following:

```
private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ABC.class .getName());
```

The following code is in the constructor of the bean.

```
try {
FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("logging.txt");
LOGGER.addHandler(handler);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
String stacktrace = sw.toString();
LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, stacktrace);
} catch (Exception logException) {
System.err.println("Logging error");
}
```

The code is writing all the logs to the console but not to the file. The log file `logging.txt` is also not getting created.

Should I create the file by myself or the path is wrong. Help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code:

```
FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("logging.txt");
```

That will create a `logging.txt` file in the appserver's default working directory. You can determine the exact path to the default working directory as follows:

```
System.out.println(new File(".").getAbsolutePath());
```

The `logging.txt` file should be in that folder.

However, this isn't the best idea. Using relative paths is a bad idea when you cannot control the default working directory from inside your application. You should use absolute paths instead. I.e., start with `/`:

```
FileHandler handler = new FileHandler("/path/to/logging.txt");
```

In Windows, this will be saved in the same disk as where the current working directory is. Otherwise, when you want to change disks as well, you would also need to prefix with `C:` or something.

Note that this problem is in no way related to JSF. You would have exactly the same problem with any other Java API/framework.

Comment: thanks it is working for absolute path.intially i got filenotfound exception then i created the folders in my C: drive and the log file was created there. But im not able to see the file in the app server either for relative or absolute path. I am running the application from RAD IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As BalusC already pointed out. The log-file will probably created in the already deployed application.

With websphere you can usually find your applications under:

WEBSPHERE_INSTALLATION_PATH/profiles/YOURPROFILE/installedApps/YOURAPPNAME.

After switching to that folder search it and the subfolders for your files. I'm not sure, but I wouldn't be suprised if you find it in the WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Normally, appserver's working directory is its own `/bin` folder. However if you're executing it by an IDE, it's the project's root folder. Or if you're executing it using command console, then it's the currently opened folder. I have never seen a setup where it is `/WEB-INF/classes`. Or you must be manually running it from command prompt while sitting in that folder.

Comment: oh stackoverflow wiped out parts of my path :) One shouldn't use less than and larger than unescaped.

Comment: Doesn't matter. It boils down to that the working directory depends on the way how you started the server and that this is in no way controllable from inside the application's code. If you stared Webspere from example inside Eclipse or IntelliJ or command prompt or even as service, the working directory would be completely different. Thus, relying on it is an extremely bad idea.

Comment: I agree that I wouldn't rely on such a path and I exspecially wouldn't code any application logic using relative pathes. AFAIK with websphere the file should pop up there.